# How to get values of a field before submitting a form in mui + formik?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have to use the value of one field before submitting the form to verify the particular field. I use the onChange event to do the same, but the value is not shown on the field. and the remains empty. I am using Mui and Formik.

The starting setup is here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-night-5rsrq2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

are the code like these

```
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: {
  email: "Lorem",
  password: 'Lorem',
},
validationSchema: validationSchema,
onSubmit: (values) => {
  console.log(values);
},});

<TextField
      id="email"
      name="email"
      label="Email"
      value={formik.values.email}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
 helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
  />
```

> you can get the data frome the "values" make sure `formik.handlechage`
> present on the component MUI